# Check Array for Changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, html5-canvas, compare

Working on a Javascript/HTML5-canvas game, I'm trying to make a function stop once water is finished filling up areas by setting an array `waterTilesCheck` equal to the original `waterTiles` array at the beginning of the function, and then comparing them at the end. If changes have been made to the original water array I want the function run again, however if there are no changes by the end of running the function I want it to stop running by saying `waterComplete = true`. Every object in the `waterTiles` array has x, y, width, height, and tag attributes, but the tag attribute is the only one that needs to be compared.

```
function fillWater (modifier) {
    waterTilesCheck = waterTiles;
    for (var i = 0; i < waterTiles.length; i++) {
        //get tiles to the left, right, above and below of i
        var l = i - (worldDim.height + 1);
        var r = i + (worldDim.height + 1);
        var u = i + 1;
        var d = i - 1;
        //just a sample of some of the logic used to move water
        if (tiles[i].tag != "none"
            && u < tiles.length
            && waterTiles[i].tag == "water"
            && waterTiles[u].y >= worldDim.top * X * 2) {
            waterTiles[u].tag = "water";
            waterTiles[i].tag = "none";
        }
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < waterTiles.length; i++) {
        if (waterTiles[i].tag == "water") {
            worldWaterCount++;
        } else {
            waterTiles[i].tag = "none";
        }
    };
    waterCheck();
    console.log(waterComplete);
};
```

`waterCheck` is the function I tried to compare arrays:

```
function waterCheck () {
    for (var i = 0; i < waterTiles.length; i++) {
        var check = Object.is(waterTiles[i].tag, waterTilesCheck[i].tag);
        if (!check) {
            waterComplete = false;
            return;
        }
    };
    waterComplete = true;
    return;
};
```

Object.is seemed like a nifty trick but didn't work, and just comparing `waterTiles[i].tag == waterTilesCheck[i].tag` didn't seem to work either which confuses me. So now I'm stuck and open to suggestions ...

Full code: https://gist.github.com/TuckerFlynn/3d73d0d6d8e636743ff9

Run in your browser to see what the game is, the water functions are around line 500

Comment: what is the tag attribute? string, array, object, etc

Comment: it's a string, either "water" or "none"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you're not actually setting waterTilesCheck to a snapshot of waterTiles. You're setting it to point to the same array. So any changes you make to waterTiles will also affect waterTilesCheck. (You'll run in to the same problem at the object level if you just copy the elements one by one -- you need to copy at the level of the immutable elements (strings, ints, etc.)). Try this:

```
var originalTags = [];
for (var i = 0; i < waterTiles.length; i++) {
  originalTags.push(waterTiles[i].tag);
  ...
}
waterCheck(originalTags);
```

and in waterCheck:

```
function waterCheck(originalTags) {
  for (var i = 0; i < waterTiles.length; i++)
    if (waterTiles[i].tag !== originalTags[i]) {
      waterComplete = false;
      return;
    }
  waterComplete = true;
  return;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I didn't realize that setting arrays in that way would change with the original!